# Keypress event of textbox using get and set property in vb.net

Tags: properties, eventhandler

This is my code as i want to validate my textbox using charracter not number so i m using keypress method
but i want to use it with get and set property using try catch block to pass the value from keypress event. But i am not able to do it

```
Public Class Form1
Property validatefirstname() As String
    Get
        Return TextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Try
            If (value <> "") Then
                TextBox1.Text = value
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("please input firstname")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Set
End Property
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 90 And Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
        e.Handled = True

        MessageBox.Show("enter only alpha")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this one , It will work for you

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

     If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "[^a-zA-Z\b]") Then
           e.Handled = True
        End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: i can able to validate but i want to achieve the result by using properties with exception handling, Is there method where i can validate my textbox using properties(get and set)in the try catch block